# how to enter a customer ID as a string containing only numbers,, but using char, program C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int valid = 0;
int length = 0;
int i = 0;
char custID[21];
do{
    puts("\nPlease enter a customer ID:");
    scanf("%s", custID);
    length = strlen(custID);
    if(length < 21){
        for(i=0;i<=length;i++)
        valid=1;
    }
    else{

        valid = 0;
        printf("\nNot valid! - the customer Id should have no more than 20 characters , you have enterd %i",length);
    }

}while(valid!=1);
return 0;
}
```

how to enter a customer  ID as a string containing only numbers,, but using char, program C?

Comment: What does "but using char" mean?

Comment: I mean the variable should be char not int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check each element of `custID` for valid numbers as :-

```
if(length < 21)
{
  valid = 1;
  for(i=0; i < length; i++) // Notice < only
     if( custID[i] <'0' || custID[i] >'9' )
     {
        valid=0;
        break ;
     }

  if(!valid)
      printf("ID should contain only numbers");
}
```

Comment: however i have a small problem i want to save them in array which is 
records[pCount].Customer[i] = custID[i];

could you please show me where i can put this code

Comment: @SalehKeshko may be after while loop, because after that only your `valid` will be 1, i.e. `custID` has valid length and valid elements in it. So copy element wise using a loop into your destination array.

Answer (score 1):

Use this scanf format:

```
scanf("%[0123456789]", custID);
```

Using this the scanf accept only numbers in your entered string

Example:

If your entered "Str78in69g", custID variable will contain only 7869